Why do my random-orbit sanders chatter over the wood surface?
With the sanding plate tight to the wood surface the R-O-S will run smoothly for a few seconds and then start vibrating or "chattering", as if the frequency of the mechanism was setting up some sort of temporary harmonic.  I can avoid the chattering by feathering the base plate against the surface but I'm sure that's a no-no.  I think I'm doing something wrong because it has happened with 2 different R-O-Ss over the years, a Ryobi cordless and a corded Dewalt. It happens regardless of the grit. (If it's relevant, the sanders are both 8-hole hook-and-loop.
This chattering has been a problem for a variety of situations, mostly with well-supported pieces. I put very little pressure on the sander and still it starts to vibrate/resonate periodically during a sanding job. The resonating stops if I slightly angle The base of the sander.

How much force are you using to hold the sander down?

What do you mean by ‘feathering’? Tipping it at an angle?

Is the piece you are sanding fully supported? If not, it could be resonating.
